# How to refresh canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, .net-4.0, refresh

I am trying to create a visual representation of any sorting algorithm where the data is represented in an int[] array. An example of bubble sort on wikipedia:

[image: Bubble sort from wikipedia]

My sorting algorithms all raise an event ItemsSwapped when two items in the int[] array are swapped. I am trying to display the data after every event on canvas, this is my code:

```
// Handler for ItemsSwapped event.
private void Render(object sender, ItemsSwapEventArgs e)
{
    canvas.Children.Clear();
    int numberOfElements = e.Data.Length;

    for (int x = 0; x < numberOfElements; x++)
    {
        RenderValue(x, e.Data[x]);
    }
    // Here I should somehow refresh canvas.
}

private void RenderValue(int x, int y)
{
    var value = new Ellipse
                    {
                        Width = 5,
                        Height = 5,
                        Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                        StrokeThickness = 2,
                    };
    Canvas.SetTop(value, x);
    Canvas.SetLeft(value, y);
    canvas.Children.Add(value);
}
```

The problem is, that the canvas doesn't refresh itself, it just displays the final solution after some time. How can I refresh it after every raised event?

Edit - I tried with UpdateLayout, InvalidateMeasure and Dispatcher object, but neither worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you start your sort algorithm on the UI thread, so it won't update until finished. Try sorting in another thread and update the Canvas children using the [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx), by calling [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) or [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke.aspx).

If your `ItemsSwapped` handler is called from a separate thread, it may look like this:

```
private void Render(object sender, ItemsSwapEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            canvas.Children.Clear();
            int numberOfElements = e.Data.Length;

            for (int x = 0; x < numberOfElements; x++)
            {
                RenderValue(x, e.Data[x]);
            }
        }));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using threads? You must do your work in a separate thread from the main UI. Here is a link to get you started: [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)